# Make docker exit on any command failure in docker-entrypoint.sh

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-ssm, docker-entrypoint

I'm trying to load AWS SSM Parameters in my `docker-entrypoint.sh` I'm testing the failure case and it continues to the CMD if it fails.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eo pipefail

ssm_available() {
  if [ -z ${SSM_BASE_PATH+x} ]; then
    return 1
  fi

  return 0
}

get_ssm_params() {
  aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --no-paginate --path ${SSM_BASE_PATH} --with-decryption --query Parameters | \
  jq -r 'map("\(.Name | sub("'${SSM_BASE_PATH}'";""))=\(.Value)") | join("\n")'
}

exec_with_ssm_parameters() {
  for parameter in `get_ssm_params`; do
    echo "Info: Exporting parameter ${parameter%%=*}"
    export ${parameter}
  done
  exec "$@"
}

main() {
  if ssm_available; then
    echo "Info: Loading SSM Parameters" >&2
    exec_with_ssm_parameters "$@"
  fi

  echo "Info: Starting ..." >&2
  exec "$@"
}

main "$@"
```

I've tried both `set -e` and `set -eo pipefail` but if the `aws` call fails, it will still continue to start the server.

How do I make Docker stop executing if the there are any failures in `docker-entrypoint.sh`?

EDIT: I believe it's because the command is completing successfully, but I'm not handling errors in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --no-paginate --path ${SSM_BASE_PATH} --with-decryption --query Parameters` is not failing so will not trigger any non-zero exit code handling.

Instead you should deal with the empty response from the `get_ssm_params` function in the `exec_with_ssm_parameters` function by checking if the response exists.

Something like the following using the `-z` flag to test whether the string is empty should resolve your issue:

```bash
exec_with_ssm_parameters() {
  local params=$(get_ssm_params)

  if [ -z "$params" ]; then
    echo "Error: No SSM parameters found"
    exit 1
  fi

  for parameter in $params; do
    echo "Info: Exporting parameter ${parameter%%=*}"
    export ${parameter}
  done

  exec "$@"
}
```